# Callback error argument naming convention in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, naming-conventions

In most examples found for `nodejs`, the callbacks which receive error argument are named as `err` and not `error`

For example, if one looks into the  [express error handling docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), all error arguments are named as `err`. Although, other names are also shortened like `req`, `res`, they aren't in [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/), but one would notice that `err` is used there as well.

Is there a particular reason for such naming convention?
Is it maybe to:

- avoid confusion with `console.error` which might have been destructured earlier?
- or `Error` object?
- or just a placeholder for the user to decide and put a meaningful error argument name instead of `err`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular reason for such naming convention. I have seen examples where it was shortened to just `e` or where full `error` was used. It is a good practice to use the same naming convention in your project, but there are no "global" conventions.